# Atribuir valor de um cursor a uma coluna da tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Tenho um cursor. Preciso em um insert ir inserindo o valor de cada posição do cursor a uma tabela. Como eu faço isso? Preciso inserir o valor do cursor `exame_cur`. 
Meu código abaixo:

```
set nocount on
declare 
@id_xfc int,
@id_exm_rea int,
@id_oit int

declare exame_cur cursor
 for
 select distinct er.id_exm_rea from t_cmo_Exame_Realizado er 
 inner join t_cmo_planilha_leitura pl on er.ID_XFC = pl.ID_XFC
 inner join t_cmo_exame ex on er.id_exm = ex.ID_EXM
 where er.id_exm = 3936 and pl.NO_EXM = 'TÓRAX: P.A.' and er.NO_RX in(select pl.RX_NUM from t_cmo_planilha_leitura pl)
 order by er.id_exm_rea

 open exame_cur
 fetch next from exame_cur into @id_exm_rea

 select max(id_oit) as id_oit into t_id_oit_1 from t_cmo_oit1980

 --insert into t_cmo_oit1980_temp1(id_oit) select id_oit from t_id_oit_1

 while @@fetch_status = 0
 begin
    insert into t_cmo_oit1980_temp1
    select
    (select id_oit + 1 from t_cmo_oit1980_temp1),
    (@id_exm_rea)

 end

 CLOSE exame_cur
 DEALLOCATE exame_cur

select * from t_cmo_oit1980_temp1
go
```

Meu código acima está correto?

Atualizei o código para o acima, e ao executar está demorando bastante. Postei essas linhas e ainda não terminou.

Comment: não entendi bem sua pergunta, você quer inserir os dados que estão no cursor? se for isso é só usar as variávies, por exemplo `insert into t_cmo_oit1980_temp1 values (@id_exm_rea)`. Se for outra dúvida, por favor explique um pouco melhor.

Comment: É isso mesmo, acontece que quando eu fui inserir, estava com erros e não inseriu, mas o sistema abriu o cursor e agora não consigo fechar. Sempre que tento inserir dá a msg que já existe um cursor aberto e não sei como eu fecho o cursor por fora.

Comment: Executei o close e deallocate sepadao, fora do bloco e resolveu.

Comment: Está demorando demais e não carrega nada. O que eu quero é só gerar registros na tabela oit1980, gerando o id_oit(PK) que é max + 1 e inserir para cada id o id_exm_rea, que é o que vem do cursor. Agora se houvesse outra forma de inserir, sem a necessidade do cursor, ficaria feliz.

Comment: Entrou em loop infinito e repetiu o mesmo registro quase 1 milhão de vezes.

Comment: Sim, você precisa repetir o comando `fetch` para pegar o próximo registro. Você deve repetir o `fetch` antes do `end` do seu loop

Comment: @RicardoPontual, antes do end eu faria isso? `fetch next from exame_cur into @id_exm_rea`

Comment: Ricardo, era isso mesmo. Agora funcionou. Transforme seu comentário em resposta, para eu fechar o post.

Comment: Ok, respondido. Obrigado @pnet

Comment: Você sabe que você não precisa de um `cursor` pra isso, certo?

Answer (score 0):

Faltou apenas usar a variável que o fetch carregou com o valor no `insert` e fazer o `fetch` novamente dentro do laço `while`:

```
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    -- aqui, verificar se o insert está correto usando @id_exm_rea
    insert into t_cmo_oit1980_temp1 values (@id_exm_rea)

    -- aqui pega o próximo valor do cursor
    fetch next from exame_cur into @id_exm_rea
end
```